# How to check version of Spark and Scala in Zeppelin?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, version, apache-zeppelin

When I run interactive spark-shell, I show spark version (2.2.0) and scala version (2.11.8)

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131)
```

However, 
I want to check **which Spark and Scala version I am using with Zeppelin** (localhost)

I am not sure that Zeppelin run same spark/scala with my interactive shell.

(I checked https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/54918/how-do-i-tell-which-version-ofspark-i-am-running.html, but that is not I want because I host Zeppelin on localhost)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

for spark version you can run `sc.version` and  for scala run `util.Properties.versionString` in your zeppelin note

Comment: Thanks! Thats not only for zeppelin...